# Wordpress has a nasty redirect not allowing ssl

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I am encountering a problem with my wordpress page. I am using the sporty theme and have setup the page. Now I would like to activate SSL.

What have I done:

I changed 
siteurl and home in the wp-options table

I used the DB Migrate plugin to modify all links.

I set up my htaccess file like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I am still stuck with a redirect to the base url which start with http. Even if I remove the htaccess this happens, so i doubt the htaccess is the problem.

I also tried adding

```
define('WP_HOME','https://tc-eislingen.de');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://tc-eislingen.de');
```

to the wp-config.php but the nasty redirect to http stays.

Is there a redirect in the template I am missing?

**Update**
Why the downvote? I followed all the rules? Is there anything wrong why my quesiton?

Comment: Nope there are (usually) no redirects in the templates. One probable reason might be a caching plugin that has stored the old base URL. Clear any caches (if there is a caching plugin) and triple check the mentioned values in the database. Wordpress will use the site_url to redirect to.

Comment: I am using http://redirectdetective.com/ to check if there is a redirect so my cache would not be them problem. Some part of the code does it.

Comment: I don't know about that service. Is this question based on an assumption or on a real experience when requesting the website? btw: you can see any redirects in the network console of any modern browser. (enable “preserve log”)

Comment: I enabled preserve log yet I do not see anything. I can remove all my changes and then i works fine. But it will allways redirect to http...

Comment: as a general note - you should set site_url and home_url in the db - not through the `define()` function

Comment: I already wrote that i have set it in the db. As it did not work i also tried the define methode.

Comment: Try installing Force HTTPS plugin. See if that helps. https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-https-littlebizzy/

Comment: @Silve2611 if it's in db - remove the define methods. You should literally just install SSL and switch urls and it's done

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be changing .htaccess file code for it. Just change the urls in database and install

> [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/)

and activate necessary settings in it. You must change http: url you placed manually into https though.